# How to check if file exists before reading the data into data frame using Pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

My requirement is to check if the specific file pattern exists in the data lake storage directory and if the file exists then read the file into pyspark dataframe if not exit the notebook execution.

I have following working code below just to read the file into dataframe.

```
kaka_adls_path = "/mnt/kaka/pre/Source_Files/"
kaka_fac_address = "*FacKaka*.txt"
kaka_fac_address_df = spark.read.text(f"{kaka_adls_path}/{kaka_fac_address}")
```

where kaka_adls_path variable contains the location of the files
and kaka_fac_address variable contains the actual file name , it contains wildcards *FacKaka*.txt so that it should match the specific pattern file I need.

Now I want to check if the same file exists before reading the file into data frame.

Kindly help.

Comment: don't do that using spark. You work with azure, so either with some dbfs tools or use the azure lib.

Comment: have you looked at `dbutils` documentation? I would use `dbutils.fs.ls(path)` to return a list of files and then use the python `re` library to for a regular expression match the files in the directory

Answer (score 0):

- You can use Python's `glob` module to check whether there are any files matching your pattern. The following are the files present in my storage.

[image]

- Let's say you have a list of patterns that you want to check for in your directory and you want to know if any such files exist for each pattern.

```
patterns = ['*sample*.csv','*newFile*.csv','*demo*.csv']
```

- Now if you want to check whether the file/files exist for each pattern and read to Dataframe if present, then you can use the following code:

```
import glob
path = '/dbfs/mnt/repro/f1/f2/'
patterns = ['*sample*.csv','*newFile*.csv','*demo*.csv']
req_files = []
for pattern in patterns:
    x = [pattern]
    y = glob.glob(path+pattern)
    y = [ '/'+'/'.join(path.split('/')[2:]) for path in y]
    x.extend(y)
    req_files.append(x)
print(req_files)
```

[image]

- Now, create the required dataframe. I have used dictionary to map pattern with dataframe if files are present.

```
dfs = {}
for pattern_matched_files in req_files:

    #checking whether files exist for the pattern
    if(len(pattern_matched_files[1:])!=0):
        #print(f"Files present for pattern: {pattern_matched_files[0]}, reading files")
        dfs[pattern_matched_files[0]] = spark.read.option("header",True).csv(pattern_matched_files[1:])
    else:
        #print(f"no files matching the pattern: {pattern_matched_files[0]}")
        dfs[pattern_matched_files[0]] = None
```

[image]